# Do function calls within a function's argument list deepen the stack?

Tags: c++, inline, callstack, calling-convention

When calling `F(argument_expression)`, is `argument_expression` evaluated before pushing the stack for F?

For example, when calling `F(G(H(arg)))`, does the compiler first push the stack for H, evaluate H, pop, then push the stack for G, etc? Or does it first push the stack for F, then for G, then for H, then pop back up 3 layers?

Also, is one way any faster than the other?

Comment: On what architecture? C++ is a language, not a platform. Also, it doesn't matter which is faster.

Comment: @GMan That is correct if you change the wording to "It **usually** doesn't matter which is faster." I for one can attest to how annoying it is to have unoptimized code have a very noticeable impact even if it only results in a few instructions in a tight loop. So, 99% of the time it doesn't matter, maybe even 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @Lodu: Or perhaps we can have an understanding that generalizations aren't expected to hold in all cases, which I though went without saying. Would you find it a useful if in reply to "Cutting people with knives is bad," I said, "Unless you're a surgeon"? It may be true, but it misses the point.

Comment: Why would being faster not matter?

Comment: In this case, we don't know if SuperElectric is playing surgeon or not do to a lack of knowledge about the context. This is less like saying "I'm going to cut someone with a knife" and more like saying "I am going to make a 1.5 inch incision over such and such an artery in the left upper arm" in which case there actually may be a reason to cut, as that sounds like a medical procedure to me. Cutting is bad 99% of the time, but in that case I wouldn't say so. Since I don't know who's accomplished or not, I prefer "difference is negligible." Just my opinion; just commenting not chastising.

Comment: @SuperElectric: For low level details like this, being faster usually does not matter because the difference is so small that you usually should not waste your time caring about it. For example, your virtual function calls in C++ can make your program slower than if you were to just use C and not have access to that. But the difference does not matter, because it happens seldom enough that it still looks instant to the end user. If you're just making an average GUI app, You can do lots of things that are 10x slower but it doesn't matter, the end user might not notice the half-second difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are fully evaluated before the called function can run, per spec.

I.e.: In your example, `H(arg)` will be fully evaluated before `G(result of H(arg))` can run, etc.

At any given time you'll have one-level depth of the stack.

Comment: From the programmer's point of view, yes, there is a well-defined evaluation order.  But the compiler is free to manage the stack however it sees fit.  The two are not necessarily related.

Comment: @Oli, I'm not sure because there should be a sequence point **at the entry** to the function, so at that point the previous function should have been called, and returned with a value. I cannot see why, and how, compiler would have more than one frame depth.

Comment: Sequence points are again from the programmer's viewpoint.  I'm talking about how the compiler implements that at the machine level.  (Note that I'm not claiming that any compiler does such a thing, merely that it's possible, and the standard in no way (AFAIK) prevents it.)

Comment: @Oli, I think the point is not to rely on that, which I agree with you. From the performance point of view, the benefit of this should be benchmarked, not discussed on a theoretical level.

Answer (score 3):

You've actually asked two orthogonal questions.

The concept of *evaluation* is pitched at the programmer's vantage point, and in this case, is well-defined by the C++ standard.  Yes, the argument to a function is always evaluated before that function is called.

However, the standard does not specify how the stack should be managed.  The compiler is free to take either of the approaches that you've suggested.  Of course, it may take a third option, which is to directly inline one or more of your nested functions.  There are probably other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are evaluated sequentially (only one frame-deep in this case).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Is it really? There is a sequence point between the evaluation of the argument to a function and entering the function itself, so the standard requires the `h(arg)` function call to be completed *before* entering `g(...)` in the expression `g( h(arg) )`. Of course, in implementations where the calling function is the one that adjusts the stack frame, the compiler can be allowed to waste space in the stack here... or anywhere else.

Comment: @David: Yes, I fully agree that from the programmer's point of view, `h(arg)` must be fully evaluated before `g()` can get going.  But that's not to say that the compiler couldn't choose to push the stack for `g`, and then push the stack for `h`, then execute `h`, then pop `h`'s stack, and then carry on with `g`.  Obviously, it can't begin executing any code in `g` that relies on the return value of `h` before `g` has completed, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Would you care to point us to the compiler that does such silly thing?

Comment: Like I said elsewhere, I'm not claiming that any compiler does such a thing, merely that the C++ standard places no constraints on the implementation in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you mean by pushing H,G,F 
Essential it happens this way

The return value of F is pushed and a temp variable then G is pushed (its return value and a temp variable ) finally all H is pushed, evaluated and poped. then G and finally F.

for performance if you use argument expression it should be faster. since it should not contain any jumps.

Comment: What?  How can the return value of `F` be the *first* thing that's pushed?